Preventing current between batteries
I charge 2 lithium Ion boat batteries from a single solar regulator. I have the positive leads from both batteries in common to the regulator and charging is fine. But if charge current is low I want to isolate one of the batteries so that it cannot send current to the second battery that is discharging quickly for some reason. I use an "A-B-ALL" switch from the batteries to the boat systems but the connection to the regulator can discharge both batteries.
Could I use a zener in the feed to each battery to prevent this discharge from one to another? Will this ruin the charging current to the batteries? ANy thoughts on which part to use?

What you are asking for A: does not address the problem you are experiencing which appears to be excessive current draw or a defective battery and B: will not work because reconnecting the unbalanced batteries will damage them.
